# Updating a user defined object in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am working with classes and arrayLists, i want to update an element(object) in the ArrayList.
fist i searched for it, by the ID number. then I reseted the object members using a method in the class that prompt user for input..

the problem is, it update all the objects in the list not one in particular.

my work

```
if (studentList.isEmpty())
    System.out.println("\t\tNO DATA TO UPDATE !!");
else {
    try {
        System.out
                .print("\n\tTo Update info, Please Enter Students ID: ");
        System.out.flush();
        searchID = obj.readLine();
        for (Iterator<Student> it = studentList.iterator(); it
                .hasNext();) {
            Student S1 = it.next();
            if (searchID.equals(S1.getID()))
                System.out.print("\n\tEnter New Data: ");
            S1.setting();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // empty
    }
}
```

it asks to update all the objects instead of one. the update works but not the way i want...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a block after your condition :

```
                        if (searchID.equals(S1.getID())) {
                            System.out.print("\n\tEnter New Data: ");
                            S1.setting();
                        }
```

Otherwise, you'll always call `S1.setting()`, regardless of the result of the condtion, since without the curly braces, the if statement only controls whether or not `System.out.print("\n\tEnter New Data: ");` will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

I've put it through my code cleaner and below is what it shows like:

```
if (studentList.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("\t\tNO DATA TO UPDATE !!");
} else {
    try {
        System.out.print("\n\tTo Update info, Please Enter Students ID: ");
        System.out.flush();
        searchID = obj.readLine();
        for (final Iterator<Student> it = studentList.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            final Student S1 = it.next();
            if (searchID.equals(S1.getID())) {
                System.out.print("\n\tEnter New Data: ");

                S1.setting();
            }
            // >>> this is where S1.setting() went wrong, moved up <<<                
        }
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        // empty
    }
}
```

The most important change is that all code blocks are with braces `{}`. If you do this it becomes very clear when a statement is executed. Without that only the first statement behind an `if` or `else` clause is executed. This makes it very easy to make coding mistakes as the one in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If  you want to conditionaly execute more than one line of code, you should put all of it betveen { ... }. If you leave it like this, only first one will depend on condition...